# when react-native run-android error

Tags: android, facebook, react-native

I tried to run the react-native run-android through my React Project. After that, I got an error like the following.

> **show error in cmd**
>
> ```
> C:\Users\ekkawit\Desktop\ReactNative\myapp>react-native run-android  
> Scanning 557 folders for symlinks in  
> C:\Users\ekkawit\Desktop\ReactNative\myapp\node_modules (15ms)  
>
> Starting JS server...
> Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...  
> Error occurred during initialization of VM  
> java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object  
> Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.  
> Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have  
> set up your Android development environment:  
> https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
> ```

I installed Android SDK and set Android Home and Path Environmental Variable successfully. But I am still getting the same error.

I also installed Gennymotion on my pc for creating virtual android device.

Answer (score 0):

You usually get this error because the emulator is not running or there is no device is connected. So first of all run the android emulator and then use `react-native run-android` inside the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

try at cmd/PS/shell:

```
    java -version
    javac -version
```

if javac returns error, then you are not installing jdk as admin. Try uninstalling your jdk, now with admin